# python bs4 html parser return null object

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the price from '[https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275994)' but it returns null object. Below is my code

```
import requests
import bs4 #beautiful soup
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.92 Safari/537.36',
    }
res = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-Programming/dp/1593275994/', headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
res.status_code
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
soup.select("#unqualifiedBuyBox > div > div.a-text-center.a-spacing-mini > span")
print(res.text[:500])
```

The code res.status.code returns 200 so it finds the site but the price value returns null. I looked if there is a sign in issue with print(res.text[:500]) but it didn't give anything about sign issue. It's output is in below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en-us" class="a-no-js a-lt-ie9 a-lt-ie8 a-lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="a-no-js a-lt-ie9 a-lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="a-no-js a-lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="a-no-js" lang="en-us"><!--<![endif]--><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrom
```

Comment: Print your soup to an HTML file and then open it in a browser. If what you see is a captcha page it means amazon identifies you as a bot.

Comment: Yes I indeed see a captcha page. Thank you but how can I bypass that?

Comment: Try to open the page with a JS browser. Selenium, Node JS Puppetteer (or its python brother Pyppeteer) requests_html or Scrapy/Splash. Possibly store the cookies as well. None of these methods are guaranteed to give reliable results though. There are more reliable options but they are not free. Don't mean to sound cynical but if you are not doing this professionally I would just give up.